# C# Making progress bar

Tags: c#, math, progress-bar

Ok im in a bit of a pickle, I am making a game, and i have experience in it.

Now for the player to level up it needs to have a curtain xp.

So Player has 20xp and he needs 40xp, I want the progress bar to show, 50% full.

Cant figure that out, and also the progress bar is 260px wide and i need it to when its 50% full, have the width of the progress bar to be 130px long, and at 100% complete i need it to be 260px wide?

Hope i gave enough info i am making a label expand to a curtain width (260%) to be my progress bar.

EDIT:

Using PictureBox to get 10xp every click to test the bar.

```
private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetXP();
    }

private void GetXP()
    {
        int XpBarWidth = 260;
        int PlayerXP = Convert.ToInt32(Exp.Text);
        int NeededXP = xp_needed;

        label1.Text = PlayerXP.ToString();
        label4.Text = NeededXP.ToString();

        int Ratio = (PlayerXP / NeededXP);

        XpBar.Width = (int)(XpBarWidth * Ratio);
        XpBar.Refresh();
    }
```

Label1 and Label4 where to test the PlayerXP and the NeededXP ints.

Comment: Any answers to this question will be making HUGE assumptions about your current set up. Post some code so we can help you with what you've tried.

Comment: Thats all i have done i have tried multiplying it i have also tried devide and adding it but nothing works

Comment: The problem is you are dividing two `int`s. I'd advise you to step into that with your debugger and have a look at the result of that division. I also updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double XpBarWidth = 260;  // maximum width of your xp bar
double Player.XP = 20;   // current xp of your player
double NeededXP = 40;   // xp needed for next lvl
double ratio = (Player.XP / NeededXP);

Label XpLabel = ... // the label where you want to display the xp
XpLabel.Width = (int)(XpBarWidth * ratio);
```

Update:
In your updated question, you define both `PlayerXP` and `NeededXP` as `int`. When you divide them, you'll get `0` as long as `PlayerXP` is less than `NeededXP`. Cast / change them to double to get correct results.

Comment: It would work perfect you have the right idea, but its not making the width any bigger

Comment: Like its not expanding

Comment: Did you set `AutoSize` on your `Label` to `false`?

Comment: Yeah its false, its just not xpanding at all, i have tried everything but you have the right idea i know that much

Comment: I just tried it here locally and it works fine. There seems to be something else with your code.

Comment: Alright i got it working but it only works when both the neededxp and the playerxp are the same :/

Comment: Please update your question with the code you've got so far. At the moment I could only guess.

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is use the progress bar that is built within the Winform namespace.

So in your instance you would set the Value of the progress bar each level up

So the steps are

- Drag New progress bar //Set width

[image: New Form]

then when ever you want to level up or add experience

```
        private void LevelUp()
        {
            progressBar1.Maximum = 100; //new experience needed
        }

        private void ShowExperience(int xp)
        {
            progressBar1.Value += xp; // Add the xp
        }
```

So that is your experience bar, and the increase in experience as well

I have also included a link to a working example below

http://tinyurl.com/pflyvhu

Link to styling the Progress Bar

http://www.dotnetperls.com/progressbar

Some Styling Code

```
            progressBar1.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            progressBar1.ForeColor = Color.White;

            // you can also use images

            progressBar1.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap("");
```

Comment: I tried that but i wanted to make a custom one, with custom colors, so im using the label method.

Comment: why dont you just set the color of the progress bar using the color settings ?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, there is no FormStyle in the properties

Comment: Thanks but i think ill stick to the label idea. but thanks anyway ill use it if i can figure this out

Comment: I have just added some examples of Color and Image use

Comment: Is there anyway to change the FormStyle to Fixed Single, im still on 2010 visual studio and im on windows 7 so it doesn't look as cool

Comment: If you do ProgressBar.Style it opens up alot of form styling such as borders etc

So you will have in my example

progressBar1.Style =

Comment: You can set the `FormBorderStyle` to `FixedSingle` just fine in VS2010.

Comment: What button? In VS, you select your form and in the properties change `FormBorderStyle` to `FixedSingle`. (Or do it from your code...)